# Accessing Computer on Same Network

Tags: perl, networking, command-line, network-programming, automation

On Computer A (my computer), I have a Perl script that accesses a file directory on Computer B, a computer on the same network. My Perl script accesses that computer because I have linked it to my R:drive.

Now let's say I want Computer C (an computer designed for automation) to run this script. I **cannot** map Computer B to a drive, as Computer C is used solely for automation. I have access to Computer C's command line, and am running Jenkins on it for automation.

To further complicate things, Computer B requires a username and password to sign in.

To map it, I entered the typical 12.345.67.89 and Username and Password. Again, Computer C has no monitor and cannot do this manually.

So here is my question: does Perl **or** the command line have any capability to do this? Essentially, can I sign into this network computer for a single session, using the username and password, every time I want to access the necessary files?

Comment: What network do you use?

Comment: EDIT: Just asked somebody. We run a Windows Domain here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to map a drive from the command-line, that's easy enough.

[net use](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 2):

You could access the resources on computer B via a [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29). No need to map/mount the disk. Just make sure the AD user the code will be running at has access to the target location, and you don't need to worry about authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a drive using the external command `net use x: \\computer name\share name`. To run this command you can use `open(PIPE, "command|")` construction.